# Inner border for TD not following overflow:hidden rule

Tags: html, css, styling

[image]

I'm trying to apply a style like the one shown in the image with "Amanda John".

I have it very close to working.

My styles are as follows:

```css
td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #EFF3F3;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.tr>td:first-child:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 3px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #EFF3F3;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.tr {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.td {
  border-top: 1px solid #EFF3F3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF3F3;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>I need html please </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The garish red just being an arbitrary colour picked while styling, it will be changed later.

The problem I'm facing is that the overflow rule isn't being obeyed, I'm getting the following:

[image]

As you can see the red content is flowing out/over the td border, and I'm having trouble figuring out what is causing the issue. Anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

As an aside, what is this sort of styling called? I've had a lot of trouble finding anything related to doing this, mainly because I have no idea what exactly to search for.

Comment: I made a snippet of your CSS please add some HTML to the table that reproduces your issue.

Comment: You might also consider other markup than a table to enhance your ability to style it.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry for the long silence! I figured out that I needed to have `overflow: hidden; position: relative;` set on the `td:first-child` style :)